# Dockerized spring cloud gateway can reach dockerized keycloak via his public dns

Tags: docker, microservices, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2

In a microservices architecture, I have three containers, front(angular), gateway(spring cloud gateway) and security provider(keycloak) among others

For security configurations in the gateway

If I set

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: http://keycloak-container:8080
```

I can start gateway container and reach the security container

But

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: https://public-dns-of-keycloak-container.mydomain.com
```

Throws me this error

```
... 61 common frames omitted

Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://public-dns-of-keycloak-container.mydomain.com/auth/realms/boromoi_app/.well-known/openid-configuration": 
Connection timed out (Connection timed out); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:751) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:654) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.getConfiguration(JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.java:71) 
        ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        ... 69 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
```

`https://public-dns-of-keycloak-container.mydomain.com`  is the URL used by front to reach  security container

Comment: why you gateway want to reach keycloak using public IP ? are you using any reverse proxy ?

Comment: It's the url on which keycloak instance is available. Yes i'm using reverse proxy(nginx).